# The performance improvements of using simple statements vs for loops for a large number of loops

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

I'm creating a program to simulate a simple genetic cross for many generations, and there is a method which takes in two `creature` classes and then getting their two gametes via a method in their classes. These four gametes are stored in an `array`, `gamete[]`. Then these gametes are used as the `arguments` for creating four new `creature` classes. Here, there are two possible ways to do it (`offSpring[]` is an `array` of the `creatures` class:

`offSpring[0] = new MonoCreature(gamete[0], gamete[2]);
    offSpring[1] = new MonoCreature(gamete[0], gamete[3]);
    offSpring[2] = new MonoCreature(gamete[1], gamete[2]);
    offSpring[3] = new MonoCreature(gamete[1], gamete[3]);`

OR

`for(int q = 0; q < 4; q++) {
        if((q == 0)||(q == 1)) {
            offSpring[q] = new MonoCreature(gamete[0], gamete[q + 2]);
        } else if((q == 2)||(q == 3)) {
            offSpring[q] = new MonoCreature(gamete[1], gamete[q]);
        }
 }`

This method has to be called repeatedly for hundreds, maybe even thousands of time, for a single run. As a result, performance becomes an important issue. Hence I'm inclined to go after the first part, but my teacher says that the second one is a more clean way. He understands that there would be performance loss in the second one, but still insists on it. In your view, which one of them is better?

Comment: To me, the first is much easier to read and understand, while the second is far away from being 'clean'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like your first approach - not because of performance but because of simplicity and readability. It is much simpler to understand than the second approach (which is really grubby in my point of view).

If you (or your teacher) really insist on a loop-based version, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
static final int ALLELES = 2; // or however it is called... ;)

int q = 0;
for (int first = 0; first < ALLELES; first++) {
    for (int second = ALLELES; second < 2 * ALLELES; second++) {
        offSpring[q++] = new MonoCreature(gamete[first], gamete[second]);
    }
}
```

The performance impact might not be as large as you think, because the JVM might do some optimizations like loop unrolling.

If performance really matters, you should do some benchmarks before!

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil! (Donald Knuth)

Comment: Nice answer, however, I'm unable to understand what `offSpring[q++] ` will do. I believe the snippet belongs inside the `for(int q...` loop from my question. The `offSpring[]` array has maximum length of 4, so my q can't be more/equal to 4. I guess `offSpring[q]` will be better for me here. Anyways, thanks for the answer, will try to convince my teacher.

Comment: I've forgotten to declare q. Fixed it. The snippet is the replacement of the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler most likely has *loop unrolling* optimization ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling)), so if it is faster without a loop, the compiler will change the generated bytecode accordingly.

You may check the generated bytecode in both cases and/or you could make a benchmark if you think it is important.